# Jupyter Notebook: functions don't register

Tags: python, function, connection, jupyter

I am having issues using Jupyter. I can't get any output from it, and in particular whenever I write any function that doesn't seem to `"register"` the way it does in **VS Code** for example (the text doesn't become bold and colored: pardon the crude language but I'm an absolute noobie. I'm only interested in Jupyter for mathematic and engineering calculations).

Here is the code when I open Jupyter:

```
jupyter notebook
[I 09:02:02.461 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ettore
[I 09:02:02.461 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 09:02:02.461 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 09:02:02.461 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=a48f48560c873171b625ac23a66538a815ecedc1974054d0
[I 09:02:02.461 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:02:02.462 NotebookApp]
```

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:

```
http://localhost:8888/?token=a48f48560c873171b625ac23a66538a815ecedc1974054d0
[I 09:02:02.905 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from 127.0.0.1
Apertura nella sessione del browser esistente.
[W 09:02:03.305 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/moment/locale/it-it.js?v=20220825090202 (127.0.0.1) 15.44ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py:257: UserWarning: date_default is deprecated since jupyter_client 7.0.0. Use jupyter_client.jsonutil.json_default.
  return _iterencode(o, 0)
```

Comment: Worked before? Python 3.6 is quite old. Normally, I'd say you may find you have better luck updating some, restarting, & trying again. However, if everything is working fine elsewhere, such as in VScode, you want to be careful and leave things. If you haven't installed Anaconda yet, install it & try running Jupyter from in there. Or you may want to work with an isolated virtual environment where you can install python & Jupyter. If you need to see how Jupyter should be behaving, go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) & click `launch binder` to get a temporary session.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I fixed it by installing the anaconda launcher. Now it works perfectly fine